# Composer class not found fatal error - wordpress plugin development

Tags: wordpress, composer-php, php-5.3, psr-0

I am trying to use composer to autoload my classes in a wordpress plugin.

I wish for my models and controllers to reside within the GD namespace, however I would like to put my models and controllers into their own directories.

I am facing the error message: Fatal error: `Class 'GD\ShortcodeController' not found in /.. .../src/GD/App.php on line 10`

**directory/file structure**

```
plugins
    gd
        cache
            // location for twig template cache
        public
            // location for plugin assets
        src
            controllers
                ShortcodeController.php
            models
            App.php
        templates
            test.html
        vendor
            // location for application dependencies installed via composer
            composer
                autoload_namespaces.php
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": "1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "GD": ["src/", "src/GD/", "src/GD/controllers/", "src/GD/models/"]
        }
    }
}
```

**vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php**

```
return array(
    'Twig_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/twig/lib'),
    'GD' => array($baseDir . '/src', $baseDir . '/src/GD', $baseDir . '/src/GD/controllers', $baseDir . '/src/GD/models'),
);
```

**GD/src/App.php**

```
class App
{
    private $plugin_dir;
    private $twig;

    public function init()
    {
        $shortcodes = new ShortcodeController;
        add_shortcode( 'gd', [ $shortcodes , 'gd'] );
    }
}
```

**GD/src/controllers/ShortcodeController.php**

```
<?php namespace GD;

class ShortcodeController
{
    // STUFF IN HERE
}
```

Should i be using autoload classmap instead of psr-0? How does composer deal with namespaced classes when using classmap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `"src/GD/controllers/"` in your `psr-0` here

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "GD": ["src/", "src/GD/", "src/GD/controllers/", "src/GD/models/"]
    }
}
```

But `ShortcodeController.php` file in `GD/src/controllers` folder and `namespace` is

```
<?php namespace GD;

class ShortcodeController
{
    // STUFF IN HERE
}
```

So, your `ShortcodeController.php` should be in the `src/GD/controllers/gd` folder but right now the path is `GD/src/controllers/ShortcodeController.php` and `Autoloader` is looking in to `"src/GD/controllers/gd/ShortcodeController.php"` folder (including other entries in the array) or you can change `"src/GD/controllers/"` to `"GD/src/controllers/"` in `psr-0`. Also, you are using `shortcodes = new ShortcodeController;` from root/global `namespace` so, it could be

```
shortcodes = new GD\ShortcodeController;
```

According to

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"GD\\": "GD/src/controllers/"}
}
```

your Class

```
<?php namespace GD;

class ShortcodeController
{
    // STUFF IN HERE
}
```

Should be in `GD/src/controllers/gd` folder.